# Cannot access property on undefined viewmodel javascript

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am getting the following error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined.
```

Undefined is a javascript viewmodel.  This error does not occur when running locally, or when deployed to a different environment hosted in the exact same way.

However, I have noticed that the definition of this specific viewmodel is not making it into main-built.js (using Durandal and Node.js)  In the router config I have the following:

```
   router.mapRoute('viewmodel', 'viewmodels/viewmodel.vm', 'view model', false);
```

Is there anything else I need to do to get the definition of this viewmodel into main-built.js?  As far as I can tell, all I should need to do is the router mapping.

Comment: Is your view model in the app directory?  I believe that it will include any view models that are in the physical directory regardless of whether you require them or not (I may be incorrect with that though which is why I did not post this as an answer)

Comment: Yes, it's in the app/viewmodels directory.  There are other viewmodels that are, as far as I can tell, set up identically and they are being registered.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add existing from another location and that there are no unresolved errors in the view model/

Comment: Is an old version of `main-built` being cached by the problem enviroment?

Comment: The environment it is being deployed to was set up immediately prior to deploy, and main-built is built during the deployment process.  So even it were cached, I would think that the cached version would still work.

Comment: I believe I've finally been able to track it down.  In the web.config if I set compilation = true, I don't get the error.  if I set it to false, I do get the error.  This makes no sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm pretty sure I have found the solution to my problem.

There was a check for "latestValue" on an array in knockoutjs.  It appears that when running in debug mode, it slowed the site down just enough for there to be a value to check.  When running in release mode, things sped up to the point that there was no 'latest' value.

So... bad:

```
   if ( myObject.latestValue.objArray[0] == "") { blah }
```

Good:

```
   if ( myObject().objArray[0] == "") { blah }
```